# Where is the location shown in this picture on a modern day map?

Tags: united-states, 1920s

[image: []
This image from this [site](http://www.art.com/products/p15400929-sa-i3742431/traffic-jam-at-the-new-york-entrance-of-the-holland-tunnel-new-york-city-1920s.htm) is named *Traffic Jam at the New York Entrance of the Holland Tunnel. New York City, 1920s*

As I understand, this is at Manhattan end of Holland Tunnel. I've tried, without success, to [find](http://g.co/maps/zgwj7) this place with Google Street Map. Could you give coordinates of the place on the photo? And another question: What is the building in the center of square and what was this building built for?

Comment: Looks like here's the best view of this place Google Street Map can show: http://maps.google.com/?ll=40.72416,-74.006875&spn=0.000356,0.000597&t=h&z=21&layer=c&cbll=40.72416,-74.006875&panoid=BsjuNyUqaXD91P1Ue_0GTg&cbp=12,355.89,,0,11.74 What you linked to is the Manhattan end of the "to Manhattan" tunnel - you can see that cars leave the tunnel and in the old photo they enter the tunnel.

Comment: @sharptooth: You should post that as an answer. Following your link and going back one step, you can clearly see Our Lady of Vilnius Church, which appears in the upper right corner of the OP's photo. (As far as I can tell, the building in the center of the square no longer exists.)

Comment: @sharptooth, I agree that your comment should be posted as the answer. That's a very good find!

Answer (score 3):

40°43′28.4″N 74°0′23.6″W

top of this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Vilnius_Church_%28New_York_City%29

I have to give Thompson credit because all I did was type in Our Lady of Vilnius Church coordinates.

Comment: @sharptooth should get credit (and should have posted his comment as an answer).